# Eclipse ADT stuck at 30% building workspace. Clean and build is not working

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse ADT is suddenly freezing after building workspace 30% with no additional information. I already tried to switch workspace and import only the google play library and a simple project, but it still stops in building workspace. Already tried to 
-disable automatic build -> clean all projects -> build all projects after clean

and it's still stuck at 30%. Can anyone give me a hand in this?

EDIT: now I see that the problem is that it´s stuck on "invoking Android Pre Compiler on google_play_services_lib". does this help with knowing my problem?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse Kepler Version?

Comment: Just make sure Android SDK version is the same as ADT. Mismatch versions often lead to unforseen problems with Android in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer to your problem, but if you don't have the requirement to use Eclipse and have some time at hand you might want to give [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) a try. It's an IntelliJ IDEA based, custom IDE made specifically for Android development.